# Why won't Javascript add onclick?

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

I have a function that adds an anchor/hyperlink to an element with ID "title".

```
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = "Link text";
    a.href = "http://example.com";
    a.style.fontSize = "14px";
    a.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    a.onclick = function() { alert('OK'); };

    // now add anchor to DOM
    $('title').insertBefore(a);
```

The link is added successfully to the DOM and its style attributes are set just fine, but not the `onclick`. Viz., this is what I get:

```
<a href="http://example.com" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;">Link text</a>
```

Why isn't the `onclick` added? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Setting the `onclick` attribute in JS won't actually display it in the markup. Did you actually click on your link to verify that the hander isn't firing?

Comment: FYI, if that's jQuery, the `.insertBefore()` does the opposite of what you seem to expect. It's going to put the matched `title` before the new `a`, which isn't in the DOM according to your example.

Comment: @Mathletics, you'd think I'd have done that, wouldn't you? D'oh!

Comment: ...maybe you're using the DOM `.insertBefore()`, which would behave like the DOM's `.append()` method since you're not passing a second argument.

Comment: @BlueSkies, what actually happens is what I want: the anchor appears within the `div` with id "title", but after the text that's already there on the `div`. I'd be complaining about that if it didn't work, now wouldn't I? What second argument are you talking about?

Comment: JohnK: One would think... but then see above. What second argument? The second argument to `.insertBefore()`, which designates the target child of the element against which it was invoked. You're calling a function called `$`, but you didn't explain what that function is. Since SO is practically jQuery central, it's not much of a stretch to assume that you were using jQuery. And so I was simply letting you know that the demo code you provided didn't make sense. But perhaps you're using MooTools, or PrototypeJS or some other code that uses the `$` identifier. Can't tell from where I'm sitting.

Comment: ...but if `$` ultimately returns a DOM element, then the native `.insertBefore` can take two arguments, or if the second is elided, the behavior will be identical to `.appendChild()` as I stated above *(though I forgot the `Child` part when I typed it)*. Of course the DOM API *does* also define an `.append()` method that is basically identical to `.appendChild()`, but no browsers implement it at this point.

Comment: It is in fact jQuery, which I am still learning, which is why I take the absence of a second argument [here](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) as meaning there is no second argument. But if I'm misreading the API docs, I'd appreciate your explanation of how.

Comment: What jQuery's `.insertBefore()` does is it inserts the matched elements before the target parameter. In other words, it inserts whatever was matched by `$("title")` before the new `a` element. But according to your example, the `a` is not in the DOM. Also, you're selecting elements with the tag named `title`, which can only appear in the `<head>` of a document. So I'm not sure what the intent is here.

Comment: Are you sure title is id...beacuse you are using $('title')...instead of $('#title').

Answer (score 3):

The `onclick` handler should work, even if it's not displayed as an attribute. If you really want to add the `onclick` attribute inside the HTML, [use `setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute).

Comment: If you want to see it in the html, use `a.onclick="alert('OK')"`. But while this works (and use the usual way to do it years ago), it'S not really pretty and doesn'T have any advatages (well, despite the onclick attribute showing up in the DOM).

Answer (score 2):

It *is* being added.  It just isn't showing up in the HTML.  It is being added virtually.

When you use `onclick = function` it does a virtual bind instead of actually adding the attribute.

You would need to use `setAttribute("onclick","alert('ok');")` if you need it to appear in the HTML (I'm not sure why you would need this though).